# How to convert controller action value and how to send attributes to controller action in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, controller, parameter-passing

I want to send data to controller action and I want to get value from action. But I cannot send value and I cannot convert value getting from controller to boolean, string etc..

```
contact =(List)response.sendRedirect("contact/login.action");
```

My contactController's login.action is below: (Also, I tried the boolean function)

```
@RequestMapping(value="/contact/login.action")
public @ResponseBody Map<String,? extends Object> login(@RequestParam Object data) throws Exception {

    try{

        List<Contact> contacts = contactService.login(data);

    return getMap(contacts);
    } catch (Exception e) {


    }
    return null;
}
```

My jsp codes are below:

```
    <%@page import="com.loiane.web.ContactController"%>
    <%@page import=" com.loiane.model.Contact"%>
    <%@page import="java.util.List"%>
    <%@ page language="java" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
 <%

     String result;

     List<Contact> contact;
     String loginUsername = request.getParameter("loginUsername");
     String loginPassword = request.getParameter("loginPassword");
     contact =(List)response.sendRedirect("contact/login.action");
     out.println(request.getAttribute("message"));

  if ((null != loginUsername && loginUsername.length() > 0) && (null != loginPassword && loginPassword.length() > 0)) {

    if (contact.size()>0)

    result = "{success:true}";
    else
        result = "{success:false,errors:{reason:'Login failed.Try again'}}";

} else {
    result = "{success:false,errors:{reason:'Login failed.Try again'}}";
}
%>
<%=result %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than doing response.sendRedirect to your servlet from JSP, your form should have the servlet as its action.

```
  <form action='contact/login.action' method='post'>
```

Your servlet needs to implement doPost. Having just a method called login will not work.

```
 public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse  response) throws IOException, ServletException
```

Your JSP should be the login form that sends to the servlet (via HTML, when you click submit, not via JSP code) and the servlet should do ALL of the login stuff, including the request.getParameter calls.

Then if there is a login error, the servlet should response.sendRedirect to the login form jsp.

And please note that response.sendRedirect actually sends the browser to another page.  Thus it will never return a list or any other datatype.

And you would be better off not using scriptlets in your JSP. You can do everything in the servlet. Just use the jsp like a HTML page.